# CAPTCHA integration into existing PHP form

Tags: php, html, captcha, recaptcha

Im using Google Recaptcha, and I've ended up with this piece of code. My goal is to have my already working php form to submit only when the captcha has been completed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ContactButton'])) {
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $privatekey = "6LePayETAAAAANJze7opnV6bQEX-n02p4UdZ8xfF";
    $response = file_get_contents($url . "? 
        secret=" . $privatekey . "&response" . $_POST['g-recaptcha- 
        response'] . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $data = json_decode($respose);
    if (isset($data -> success) AND $data -> success == true) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $formcontent = " From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Message: $message";
        $recipient = "magicmacaroni@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Contact Form";
        $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
        mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
        header('Location: contact-thank-you.html');
        exit();
    } else {
        header('location: index.html?captchafail=True');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not working about it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using honeytrap instead of captcha which is more simple and does the same functionality http://blog.mtstudios.net/the-honey-trap-the-easiest-way-ive-found-to-stop-spam-emails-on-asp-net-contact-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [google's developer documentation for reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro#overview) and [github page](https://github.com/google/recaptcha) that will help you